# Is Pardot Sandbox available to install for everyone

Tags: sandbox, pardot

I want to install Pardot Sandbox.
Please note that, we already have Pardot that was purchased before 2018.
We do not have a full Salesforce sandbox.

I could'nt find a clear documentation that tells me that Pardot Sandbox is available to install/ download, and test.

Can someone please point me to a document or tell me if I can download Pardot sandbox?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sandboxes for Pardot are available to customers who have either Pardot Advanced or Premium editions, a verified Salesforce-Pardot v2 connector, and an existing Salesforce sandbox. Check [Create a Sandbox for Pardot](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=pardot_sf_connector_sandbox.htm&type=5).

Review more details on Sandboxes for Pardot [here](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/pardot-sandboxes-quick-look/use-pardot-sandboxes).

Thanks